# How to order Pandas multiIndex items in non lexicographical order

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have this multiIndex

```
                                  Price
Fruit     Season     Location     

Apple     Winter     Japan          8
                     Other          5
                     China          8
Melon     Any        Africa         7
                     Other          2
                     Colombia       4
```

How can I arrange the items in Location so that 'Other' will always be the last regardless of alphabetical order of other items?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that. If you don't have too many locations, you may use `pandas.MultiIndex.set_codes` to customize the order. (see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_codes.html#pandas.MultiIndex.set_codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
                       Price
Fruit Season Location       
Apple Winter Singapur      8
             Other         5
             China         8
Melon Any    Africa        7
             Other         2
             Colombia      4
```

You can create ordered [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) for second level, then use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html), so possible use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

```
i = df.index.levels[2]
out = sorted(i.difference(['Other']))
out.append('Other')
print (out)
['Africa', 'China', 'Colombia', 'Singapur', 'Other']

df.index = df.index.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(i, ordered=True, categories=out),level=2)

df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
                       Price
Fruit Season Location       
Apple Winter China         8
             Singapur      8
             Other         5
Melon Any    Africa        7
             Colombia      4
             Other         2
```